# R difference between as.factor(x) and factor(x)

Tags: r

In R there are a lot of functions which you can use in the "as."-version. I dont understand the difference. Example:

```
a <- c("a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "c")
b <- factor(a)
c <- as.factor(a)
identical(b, c)
```

`identical(b, c)` will get TRUE. So at least in this case is no difference between `as.factor` and `factor`, both of them convert the character-vector a to a factor.
There are lots of similar examples (`as.data.frame` and `data.frame`, `as.numeric` and `numeric`, `as.vector` and `vector`, ...). Maybe somebody can explain the general difference of use between these.

Comment: You can specify `levels`, `labels` etc in `factor` when compared to `as.factor` i.e. `b <- factor(a, levels = letters[1:4]);
 c <- as.factor(a, levels = letters[1:4])#
Error in as.factor(a, levels = letters[1:4]) : 
  unused argument (levels = letters[1:4])`

Comment: `as.*` is for converting one object to another and functions without the `as.` part are for constructing objects from scratch.